# nginx can open with path / but can not with a different path on server

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to use nginx in a docker container. I created a configuration file that works with / but not with /team/soccer (I need this). In this case it goes to the site that is located on the server that contains the docker machines. Am I missing something? myserver is the name of a docker container that contains the site I need to open. docker_nginx is the name of the docker that contains nginx. All the docker machines are within a docker network. The next is the nginx.conf file:

```
    events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
#   proxy_buffering    off;    <- don't forget to comment out or remove this line.
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    # proxy_cache_path   /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:1000m;
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;

# Do gzip compression with nginx, not the play application
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_proxied any;

# This is important if you use Play chunked response as chunked response is only available with HTTP 1.1
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    upstream mybackend {
        server myserver:9000;
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       docker_nginx:80;
        #server_name  docker_nginx;

        location / {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://mybackend;
        }

        location /team/soccer {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://mybackend;
        }

 #       location ~ ^/(assets|webjars)/ {
 #           # proxy_cache one;
 #           proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri";
 #           proxy_cache_valid 200 30d;
 #           proxy_cache_valid 301 302 10m;
 #           proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

 #           proxy_pass http://backend;
#        }
    }

}
```